# How to read decimal numbers from a file which has non-English (Turkish) content in C

Tags: c, file

I have a file and I am trying to multiply the amount of unit entered with the price if the price is int, it is ok but it does not have a decimal value of 0.0000 result. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int birim;    // unit
    float birim_fiyat; // unit price
    char barkod[10]; // barcode
    char kategori[10], urunadi[10], istenen[10];
    float ucret=0.00;  //price
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
    FILE *fp=fopen("barkod.txt","r+");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        puts("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called:");
    scanf("%s",&istenen);  // find barcode

    printf("How many:");
    scanf("%d",&birim);

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,&birim_fiyat);
        if(strcmp(istenen,barkod)==0)
        {
          printf("Aranan Ürün Bulundu: %s %s\n", urunadi,kategori);
          ucret +=birim*birim_fiyat;
    }
}
```

This is my barcode file:

```
    825 Meyve sebze 12.50
    403 Cikolata Tatli 5.50
    902 Havu‡ Meyve 15.50
    881 S A 15.50
    866 Zemzem suyu 10.50
    300 Tiner Icecek 10.50
```

Comment: `it does not have a decimal` Where? The posted code does not print the total cost anywhere.

Comment: Who suggest using [`while(!feof(fp))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)?

Comment: @dxiv I can't see where the mistake is
float price:12.50
birim=10 (example)

12.5(output)

Comment: @Marilyn `12.5(output)` Again, where? There isn't one single floating point value printed anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @dxiv Inside the 12.50 barcode file. I am trying to multiply the price of the barcode number I am looking for with the price I have determined, but it gives blank output when it is float value but it is 0.0000 but it works smoothly when it is an integer.

Comment: @Marilyn Where is the line of code that "*gives blank output*"? I don't see that code in what you posted.

Comment: I suspect the line of output that gives blank results is the result of `while(!feof(fp))` leading to *Undefined Behavior* when `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,&birim_fiyat);` returns `EOF` but then the values are blindly used in `printf("Aranan Ürün Bulundu: %s %s\n", urunadi,kategori);`

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about `locale`, but it seems to be the cause of the problem in your case. I took your code and removed all Turkish letters, and tried to run. It ran fine ! Below is the quick and dirty modifications I did to your code.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int birim;    // unit
    float birim_fiyat; // unit price
    char barkod[10]; // barcode
    char kategori[10], urunadi[10], istenen[10];
    float ucret=0.00;  //price
    FILE *fp=fopen("barkod.txt","r+");
    if(fp==NULL)
      {
        puts("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called:");
      scanf("%s",&istenen);  // find barcode

  printf("How many:");
  scanf("%d",&birim);

  while(!feof(fp))
  {
  fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,&birim_fiyat);
  printf("%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,birim_fiyat);
  if(strcmp(istenen,barkod)==0)
  {
  printf("Aranan: %s %s\n", urunadi,kategori);
  ucret +=birim*birim_fiyat;

 }
  }

  printf("%f\n", ucret);

}
```

barkod.txt

```
825 Me e 12.5
403 Ci e 5.50
902 Hav e 15.50
881 S e 15.50
866 Zemz e 10.50
300 Tinev Icecek 10.50
```

Output

```
Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called:825
How many:2
825 Me e 12.500000
Aranan: Me e
403 Ci e 5.500000
902 Hav e 15.500000
881 S e 15.500000
866 Zemz e 10.500000
300 Tinev Icecek 10.500000
25.000000
```

It printed `25`, I hope this is the result you are expecting. In investigation further I tried to print a decimal value of one turkish letter.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n",'‡');
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Warnings

```
base.c: In function ‘main’:
base.c:4:16: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    4 |  printf("%d\n",'‡');
      |                ^~~~~
```

Output

```
14844065
```

As others mentioned, you may be not having appropriate checks at`fscanf()`, I am not talking about it pls go through `fscanf()` man page. And, someother needs to answer your question about how to have turkish letters in file and how to read them successfully.

#### EDIT

For completeness of the answer. From the man page of `fscanf()`

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number
>          of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be
>          zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends
>          before the first conversion (if any) has completed, and without a
>          matching failure having occurred, EOF shall be returned. If an error
>          occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed, and
>          without a matching failure having occurred, EOF shall be returned and
>          errno shall be set to indicate the error.  If a read error occurs,
>          the error indicator for the stream shall be set.

You dont know whether the file is complete (all 4 variables are indeed there) or when the file ends or when the error happens in underlying read operation. So it mandatory to have a success check after `fscanf()`. Man page says if no error happens, it returns the number of variables it read. So you can have a check like this.

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,&birim_fiyat) == 4) {
    ....... 
}
```

As @dxiv suggested the Turkish decimal separator is `,` not `.`. Based on that your `barkod.txt` should be something like this

barkod.txt

```
825 Meyve sebze 12,50
403 Cikolata Tatli 5,50
902 Havu‡ Meyve 15,50
881 S A 15,50
866 Zemzem suyu 10,50
300 Tiner Icecek 10,50
```

Then the program runs fine outputting `25,000000` (whose English equivalent is `25.000000`) when run with the inputs provided as before (`825, 2`)

Comment: A very nicely formatted answer and shows good effort -- but you really need to drive home [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong). And yes, while I agree with the subtle reference to the benefit of reading with `fgets()` and then parsing with `sscanf()` -- it is best to not leave the `while (!feof(fp))` in the answer. (fixing that and I will be happy to UV the answer)

Comment: Thanks ! I will make it complete

Comment: The only other comment I should have made in my answer as well is a caution about the array size of `10` for the barcode input string. If they are guaranteed to be 9-char or less -- that is fine, but it is a risk. The common rule is *"Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!"*. Far better to be 500 too-long than 1 too-short. Generally largest anticipated input and then double the size is a good rule of thumb (if you are on an embedded system with limited memory then 1.2 - 1.5 times may be okay)

Comment: @MohithReddy I would guess the Turkish decimal separator is a `,` comma, not a `.` dot.

Comment: @dxiv   So we need to represent ``12.5`` as ``12,5`` ? I am new to using ``locale``, but ``fscanf()`` man page has a note on ``LC_NUMERIC`` does fscanf() respects the current ``locale`` ?

Comment: @MohithReddy Right, that's what I am thinking. For a quick test, you could change the locale back to Turkish and edit the data file to use commas instead of dots.

Comment: Yes, I tried what you have said. Its perfectly working. The output is something like ``25,000000`` , and this should be meaning ``25.000000`` in English

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems:

1. You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***;
2. See: [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong);
3. Including the `&` before `istenen` in `scanf("%s", istenen` is wrong

Why?

When taking any input, regardless whether it is from the user or a file, you must check the return to determine whether the input succeeded or failed before proceeding to use those values filled by the input in the rest of your code. Otherwise, you invite *Undefined Behavior* by blindly using the variables that will be left indeterminate if your input fails. At minimum, you need, e.g.

```
    fputs ("Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%s", istenen) != 1) { // NO & - istened already a pointer
        fputs ("error: user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fputs ("How many: ", stdout);        /* just use fputs() unless a conversion needed */
    if (scanf("%d", &birim) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Which leads to why `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong. As detailed in the answer, the problem is after your last good read of values from your file, `EOF` is NOT set, you check `while (!feof(fp))` and it tests **true** and you loop again and you attempt `fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n",barkod,urunadi,kategori,&birim_fiyat);` which fails returning `EOF`, but since you do not check for `EOF` before `printf("Aranan Ürün Bulundu: %s %s\n", urunadi,kategori);` you invoke *Undefined Behavior* using `urunadi` and `kategori` while there values are indeterminate.

You fix that by using the result of the read as the test condition for you loop, e.g.

```
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n", barkod, urunadi, kategori, &birim_fiyat) == 4) {
        if (strcmp (istenen,barkod) == 0) {
            printf ("Aranan Ürün Bulundu: %s %s\n", urunadi, kategori);
            ucret += birim * birim_fiyat;
        }
    }
```

Finally as noted in the comment above, you do not place an `&` before `istenen` in `scanf("%s", istenen)`. Why? `istenen` is already a pointer by virtue of an array being converted to a pointer to the first element, [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Putting it altogether (and commenting the `setlocale` for testing on my box), you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include <locale.h>

int main (void) {

    int birim;    // unit
    float birim_fiyat; // unit price
    char barkod[10]; // barcode
    char kategori[10], urunadi[10], istenen[10];
    float ucret=0.00;  //price
    // setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
    // FILE *fp=fopen("barkod.txt","r+");
    FILE *fp=fopen("dat/barcode.txt","r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fputs("cannot open file\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fputs ("Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%s", istenen) != 1) { // NO & - istened alread a pointer
        fputs ("error: user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fputs ("How many: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &birim) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %f\n", barkod, urunadi, kategori, &birim_fiyat) == 4) {
        if (strcmp (istenen,barkod) == 0) {
            printf ("Aranan Ürün Bulundu: %s %s\n", urunadi, kategori);
            ucret += birim * birim_fiyat;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** you have nothing that requires `conio.h` so do not include that old DOS header. It makes your code 100% non-portable)

Also, unless you are writing back to the file, just open the file with `"r"` instead of `"r+"`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/barcode
Enter the Product Barcode Number to be Called: 902
How many: 10
Aranan Ürün Bulundu: Havu‡ Meyve
```

Look things over an let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I am completely aware of how to read a string into character array (not having ``&`` before the variable). But in a hurry I did not rectify it in my modified code and it still ran fine, now I am interested in how ? Do you have any thoughts ? Pls go though my answer once

Comment: @MohithReddy How is because both `istenen` and `&istenen` resolve to the same address **but are completely different types** (and thus have completely different pointer arithmetic). With [6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) `istenen` is a pointer to the first char in the array of type `char *` while `&istenen` is a *pointer-to-array of* `char [10]` which is type `char (*)[10]`. So HOW it works is due to both resolving to the same address -- but you will note the compiler warning about the case with `&`.

Comment: How ``istenen`` and the character array of 10 bytes resides in memory ? Is it not like pointers ? If suppose ``istenen`` is a pointer it would be residing somewhere else, but having the 10 bytes array address (start value of the address) as its value, then ``&istenen`` will give the address where ``istenen`` is residing in the memory. So the memory layout of ``istenen[10]`` is different from that of pointer ``*istenen`` ?

Comment: Since `lstenen` is an array or 10-bytes, those 10-bytes are guaranteed to be sequential in memory. When it is converted to a pointer, e.g. `char *p = lstenen;`, `p` is a pointer to the first character in `lstenen` and `p++;` advances by 1-byte to point to the next character. However when `&lstenen` is used, the pointer is `char (*p)[10] = &lstenen;` which points to the same address but has type *pointer to array* `char[10]` and `p++;` would advance by 10-bytes to point to the beginning of the  next `char (*)[10]` array in memory. Just writing to the address writes to the same place.

Comment: Turkish locale uses comma as decimal separator which just might be the problem alone.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I got you. These are pointer basics that I have been taught,sry I was confused . Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala -- Thank you -- the difference in local separator didn't even click given the proposed input file.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that the Turkish locale uses comma as decimal separator. This applies even to parsing file contents with `fscanf` - it expects to find a decimal `,` in the number but sees only `.` and stops at that, and after that the parsing goes off-sync.

If you're building for a POSIX-2008+ compliant system, you can use [`uselocale`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uselocale.html) to temporarily change the locale when reading/writing to/from file.

Something like:

```
locale_t clocale = newlocale(LC_ALL, "C", NULL);
locale_t old_locale = uselocale(clocale);
// read/write to file using the C locale which uses `.` as the decimal separator
// finally restore the previous locale
uselocale(old_locale);
```