# Convert an element (to be accurate: number) from array/char to type double

Tags: arrays, c, double

I want to convert some elements from an array to double (example: '2', '3', '6', ',' '9', '5' to 236,95) but it doesn't work. I tried atof() but it didn't work, because everything behind the comma is getting replaced by zeros. Typecasting also didn't do the work.

Error messages:

```
error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
   22 |  firstDoubleNum = (double)(numOne);
error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
   26 |  secondDoubleNum = (double)(numTwo);
```

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define cSizeOfNum 9

//Task 1 from Course Task
char getRealNumber(char numArr[], char numFromArr[], int size);

void comparisonOfTwoRealNumbers(double firstIntNum, double secondIntNum, int size);

int main()
{

    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
    setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    char firstValue[cSizeOfNum], secondValue[cSizeOfNum];
    char numOne[cSizeOfNum], numTwo[cSizeOfNum];
    double firstDoubleNum, secondDoubleNum;

    printf("Enter two real numbers: \n");
    getRealNumber(firstValue, numOne, cSizeOfNum);
    firstDoubleNum = (double)(numOne);

    printf("\n");
    getRealNumber(secondValue, numTwo, cSizeOfNum);
    secondDoubleNum = (double)(numTwo);

    printf("\n");
    comparisonOfTwoRealNumbers(firstDoubleNum, secondDoubleNum, cSizeOfNum);

    return 0;
}

char getRealNumber(char onlyVal[], char numFromArr[], int size)

{

    int index, anotherIndex;

    index = 0;
    while(index < size)
    {
        onlyVal[index] = getch();
        if((onlyVal[index] >= '0') && (onlyVal[index] <= '9'))
        {
            putch(onlyVal[index]);
            index++;
        }
        else if((onlyVal[index] == ',') || (onlyVal[index] == '.'))
        {
            putch(onlyVal[index]);
            index++;
        }
        else if(onlyVal[index] == '\r')
        {
            onlyVal[index] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("Invalid input! Enter again:");
            index = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    anotherIndex = 0;
    while(onlyVal[index] != '\0')
    {
        numFromArr[anotherIndex] = onlyVal[index] - '\0';
        index++;
        anotherIndex++;
    }
    return numFromArr[index < '\0'];
}

void comparisonOfTwoRealNumbers(double numberOne, double numberTwo, int size)
{

    if(numberOne > numberTwo)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%.4lf is bigger than %.4lf", numberOne, numberTwo);
    }
    else if(numberOne < numberTwo)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%.4lf is smaller than %.4lf", numberOne, numberTwo);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%.4lf is equal to %.4lf", numberOne, numberTwo);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The first step should be to change `#define cSizeOfNum 9` to something like `#define cSizeOfNum 100` so you don't get into trouble with tiny buffer sizes.

Comment: Use `setlocale` to parse numbers using comma as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61981974/1216776

Answer (score 2):

> I tried atof() but it didn't work, because everything behind the comma is getting replaced by zeros.

Well, first off, dbush's answer is correct as far as it goes: you do need to call a library function to convert a string to a `double`, and the function to use is `strtod`, not `atof`.  But *don't* give NULL for the second argument.  Supply an `endptr`, so that you can check for input errors properly, like this:

```
double xstrtod(char *s)
{
    char *endp;
    double val;

    errno = 0;
    val = strtod(s, &endp);
    if (endp == s || *endp != '\0' || errno) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number: %s\n", s);
        exit(1);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Second off, by default the C library operates in the *["C" locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02)*, and among other things that means `strtod` parses decimal fractions according to the US-English syntax: it looks for a decimal *point*, "236.95", not a decimal *comma*, "236,95".  To change this you need to set the locale to one where decimal fractions are marked with a comma.  Adding `#include <locale.h>` to the top of your program, and then adding `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` at the beginning of `main`, *may* be sufficient.  Try that first.  If it doesn't work, consult your operating system's documentation to find out what strings are accepted as the second argument to `setlocale`, find one that uses a decimal comma, and put it there instead.  (Regrettably, there is no way to just ask for decimal commas.)

[**EDIT:** It's been pointed out to me that your `getRealNumber` function doesn't produce a NUL-terminated "C string" in the array that it writes to.  You will also need to change that in order to use `strtod`.  I recommend scrapping that entire function and instead using `fgets`.]

Comment: instead of changing the locale what might invoke unwanted side effects one might consider to just copy the string and replace ',' by '.' in the copy before calling `strtod()`

Comment: On a *nix system, you can get a list of supported locale names by using `locale -a`.

Comment: As OP's array is not certainly _null character_ terminated, `strtod()` will be a problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh, isn't it? I admit I didn't read OP's code very carefully. I'll add a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a string to a `double`.  What your code is attempting to do is take the pointer value stored in `numOne` and `numTwo` and convert it to a `double`.  Such a conversion is not allowed.

What you want is to use `strtod` which converts a string to a `double`:

```
firstDoubleNum = strtod(numOne, NULL);
secondDoubleNum = strtod(numTwo, NULL);
```

Comment: What about the comma issue?